# Calculating very low pvalues Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have reached a point in my code where I iteratively calculate the pvalues of some conditions:

```
from scipy.stats import hypergeom
pval = min(hypergeom.sf(k, M, n, N) + hypergeom.pmf(k, M, n, N), 1)
```

this method works for "small" n's (number of successful elements in the pop). I tried up to 500.

After I tried with `n=5000` I get a precision error because the calculated pvalue is very low and is rounded to 0.

How can I overcome these `precision errors` in Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html Take a look at the issues and limitations of floating point numbers here.

Comment: On a related note, are you passing python floats or numpy floats?

Comment: What are typical values that you use for `k`, `M` and `N`?

Comment: Thanks.  Can you also give a specific example where you got 0 but expected a nonzero result?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser `k =  5007, M =  45956, n =  18969, N =  5267`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values that you want to compute are smaller than can be represented using 64 bit floating point values.  One example you give in a comment is `k = 5007, M = 45956, n = 18969, N = 5267`.  For those values of `M`, `n` and `N`, the PMF underflows to 0 when the `k` argument is 3478:

```
In [46]: k = 5007

In [47]: M = 45956

In [48]: n = 18969

In [49]: N = 5267

In [50]: hypergeom.pmf(3476, M, n, N)
Out[50]: 9.8813129168249309e-324

In [51]: hypergeom.pmf(3477, M, n, N)
Out[51]: 4.9406564584124654e-324

In [52]: hypergeom.pmf(3478, M, n, N)
Out[52]: 0.0
```

The standard method to work around that problem is to work with the logarithms of the probabilities.  The scipy discrete distributions have the functions `logpmf` and `logsf` for this:

```
In [53]: hypergeom.logpmf(3476, M, n, N)
Out[53]: -743.80749253381509

In [54]: hypergeom.logpmf(3477, M, n, N)
Out[54]: -744.95722489454783

In [55]: hypergeom.logpmf(3478, M, n, N)
Out[55]: -746.10790755529888

In [56]: hypergeom.logpmf(5007, M, n, N)
Out[56]: -3952.1782915849763
```

To compute `hypergeom.sf(k, M, n, N) + hypergeom.pmf(k, M, n, N)`, you can use [`numpy.logaddexp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html):

```
In [58]: np.logaddexp(hypergeom.logsf(k, M, n, N), hypergeom.logpmf(k, M, n, N))
Out[58]: -3952.1508002445375
```

The only inconvenience is that further calculations and comparisons must be based on the logarithm of the probability.  If that doesn't work for you, you'll have to switch to a library that provides higher precision floating point calculations, such as [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/).  For example, the following functions use `mpmath` to compute the PMF and the survival function:

```
def hypergeom_pmf(k, M, n, N):
    tot, good = M, n
    bad = tot - good
    pmf = (mpmath.beta(good+1, 1) * mpmath.beta(bad+1,1) * mpmath.beta(tot-N+1, N+1) /
           (mpmath.beta(k+1, good-k+1) * mpmath.beta(N-k+1,bad-N+k+1) * mpmath.beta(tot+1, 1)))
    return pmf

def hypergeom_sf(k, M, n, N):
    sf = (mpmath.binomial(N, k+1) * mpmath.binomial(M-N, n - k - 1) / mpmath.binomial(M, n) *
          mpmath.hyp3f2(1, k + 1 - n, k + 1 - N, k + 2, M + k + 2 - n - N, 1))
    return sf
```

(The expressions used in `hypergeom_pmf(k, M, n, N)` were taken from scipy's implementation in `scipy.stats.hypergeom._logpmf`.  `hypergeom_sf`  uses the formula for the CDF given on [the wikipedia page on the hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  It is not necessarily the best implementation of the survival function.)

For example:

```
In [107]: import mpmath

In [108]: mpmath.mp.dps = 40

In [109]: k, M, n, N
Out[109]: (5007, 45956, 18969, 5267)

In [110]: hypergeom_pmf(k, M, n, N)
Out[110]: mpf('3.897413335837289136238051958307757561884655e-1717')

In [111]: hypergeom_sf(k, M, n, N)
Out[111]: mpf('1.086314878026431217760059547783856962636701e-1718')
```

Comment: if it's not too much to ask can you provide a quick example of `mpmath`?

Comment: @Jack: I added an example of using `mpmath` to compute the PMF and the survival function.